# Merge feature branch with parent branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I have created a feature branch(parent branch is v8.2) 2 weeks ago. Now i have few code changes made in feature branch. I have to integrate this feature branch with its parent branch.

can i follow following steps:

```
git checkout -b "topic branch" origin/v8.2
git merge feature-branch
```

and whats the difference in doing this

```
git checkout -b "topic branch" origin/feature-branch
git merge parentbranch
```

please let me know as i am new to git this is bit confusing.

Comment: `git checkout v8.2` followed by `git merge feature-branch` should merge the feature branch into the parent. `v8.2` sound more like a tag than a branch, though.

Comment: Yes this is what i want. i want to take all my changes from feature branch to parent branch. Is these steps fine to do.  ?

Comment: feature-branch i gave that as a general name.. thats not  the actual name of my feature branch

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. Is it called "topic branch" or feature-branch? What is parentbranch? What exactly do you want to merge where?

Answer (score 3):

First, blanks—white space in general-are [not allowed in branch names](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html):

> ```
> git checkout -b "topic branch" origin/v8.2
> ```

I think you were trying to imply, with the quote marks, that you had not yet chosen a specific branch name here, but it really does matter, and assuming things not in evidence is generally not good procedure (in real life as well as in court :-) ).

## What names are for

Let's change this to:

```
git checkout -b foobranch origin/v8.2
```

and contrast it to:

```
git checkout -b foobranch origin/feature-branch
```

Both of these create a new branch *name*.  The difference, if any—there could be *no* difference, in the general case—lies in which commit ID the new name points-to.

#### Human readable names, vs Git's internal SHA-1 hash "true names"

Before you run either command, run these two commands and note their output:

```
git rev-parse origin/v8.2
git rev-parse origin/feature-branch
```

The actual output, from each command, will be some 40-character SHA-1 hash.  Let's just say, for easy typing and reading, that the first one produces `a000000...` (with all the `.`s being something easy to read and remember, but that I already forgot :-) ), and the second prints `c000000...`.

These are obviously different.  What they *are* is the "true name" of two commits.

#### Commit graphs

Next, you should draw a graph of your commits, or at least some of them.  Drawing graphs is not a lot of fun, but is necessary to understand what Git is going to do.  Fortunately there are programs that draw the graphs for you, although they tend to draw very messy looking graphs.

Here is my drawing, which is at best a guess, and is based on this claim:

> I have created a feature branch(parent branch is v8.2) 2 weeks ago. Now i have few code changes made in feature branch.

I am guessing, for now, that `feature-branch` is the name of the feature branch you created two weeks ago, and that `origin/v8.2` still points to the *same* commit it pointed-to two weeks ago.

That is, two weeks ago, if you had run `git rev-parse origin/v8.2` it would still have shown `a000000...`.

Furthermore, I am guessing that since then you made exactly two commits (the number is not that important, it just affects the graph drawing), and you have done `git push origin feature-branch` at some point recently.

Then, what you have now can be drawn like this:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
```

In other words, the *name* `origin/v8.2` *points to* commit `a000000...` (which, for graph drawing purposes, I further compressed to just the letter `A`).  Meanwhile, the *name* `origin/feature-branch` points to commit `c000000...` (aka `C`), and in fact, the name `feature-branch` *also* points to this same commit.

Note that every commit points back to its parent commit.  Here `C` points back to `B`, and `B` points back to `A`.  (The `--` connectors should really be arrows, `<-`, but it's hard to draw proper arrows, especially when they need to point up-and-left like the one from `B` to `A`, so we just use lines here.)

What `git rev-parse` does is take a human-readable name like `origin/v8.2` and turn it into one of these hashes.  This is basically *all* it does,<sup>1</sup> and the main point of human-readable names is, well, that they are human-readable.

When you run `git checkout -b new-name existing-name`, you are asking Git to create a *new* branch *name*, pointing to the *same commit* as some existing name.  You can replace the *`existing-name`* part with the raw SHA-1 hash ID and get the exact same effect.

## The one extra-special property of a local branch name

Before we create any more branch names, let's note that you can do this:

```
git checkout origin/v8.2
```

If you run this command, Git will check out the commit that `origin/v8.2` names.  In my drawing, this is commit `a000000...` (or commit `A` for very-short).  However, the `checkout` command will also print a somewhat scary message about going into "detached HEAD" mode.  Now `HEAD` is no longer a branch *name*; instead, it has a raw commit ID in it, so that your current *commit* is `a000000...`.

What this means is that you are *no longer "on" a branch*.<sup>2</sup>  If that's a bit scary, you can run `git checkout -b newbranch` to create a new branch.  Note that this form does not specify a particular commit.  This means "use the current commit".  What's the current commit?  Well, we just said it was `a000000...`.  So this makes `newbranch` point to commit `a000000...`, and then gets on the new branch `newbranch`.

#### What does it mean to be "on a branch"?

It's surprisingly simple: you are "on a branch" if `HEAD` contains a branch *name* instead of a raw commit hash.  If `HEAD` says `ref: refs/heads/master`, you're `on branch master`, as `git status` would say.  If it says `ref: refs/heads/feature-branch`, you're on `feature-branch`.  But if it has a raw commit hash like `a000000...` in it, you're "not on any branch".

The advantage to being on a branch comes up when you *make new commits*.

Let's go back to that graph again.  I'll use a slightly different one, with the same general shape, but one different name:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C   <-- HEAD->foo
```

This time I've written in the name `HEAD` too, so that we know that `HEAD` names branch `foo`, which means we're on `foo`.  Now let's make a new commit:

```
$ ... modify some files ...
$ git commit -a -m new-commit
```

so that we get new commit `D`:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C--D   <-- HEAD->foo
```

The name `foo` now points to commit `D`, which we can tell by running `git rev-parse foo`.  The name `HEAD` still says `foo`: we haven't changed which branch we're on.  What we *have* changed is that we added new commit `D` and made `foo`, the current branch name, point to `D`.

If we are doing all of this in the same repository, we still have `feature-branch` and `origin/feature-branch`.  What happened to them?

Nothing!  Let's draw them in—I'll have to move `D` down a row just to squeeze them in though:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
           \
            D   <-- HEAD->foo
```

#### New commits move the branch pointer of whichever branch you're on

That's it: that's the extra-special property of a (local) branch.  (You cannot get "on" a remote-tracking branch; if you try, you get that "detached HEAD" thing.  So this property is exclusive to ordinary branches.)

## Merging

You really need to understand all of the above before you tackle merging, because `git merge` can do more than just one thing.

A *merge commit* is a commit with two (or more) parents.  In a graph, it looks something like this `M`:

```
...--A--E--F--M
      \      /
       B----C
```

Instead of just one parent arrow pointing to either `C` or `F`, it has two, one pointing to each parent commit.

You might expect `git merge` to make such commits, and it does—but *only if necessary*.

We drew our graph earlier like this:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
```

If we are now "on feature-branch" (add `HEAD->` as appropriate) and we say `git merge origin/v8.2`, Git will do *nothing*.  (Well, it will compute a bit, say "Already up to date, nothing to merge", and *then* do nothing.)

The reason is that there is no work from commit `A` that is missing from commit `C`.  Note that commit `C`'s parent is `B` and `B`'s parent is `A`: this means `B` may have some changes from `A`, and `C` may have some from `B`, but `A` has none to bring in: they're all already in there.  More precisely, `A` is an ancestor of `C` (in this case, a grandparent).  So there is no work to merge in and nothing to do.

Note that, to get here, `git merge` first had to run `rev-parse` on `origin/v8.2` to find that it points to commit `A`.  This is one of the keys to understanding `git merge`: whatever arguments you give it, it translates to some *specific commit*.

OK, so, suppose we check out a new branch and point it to commit `A`:

```
git checkout -b temp origin/v8.2
```

Now the drawing looks like this:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2, HEAD->temp
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
```

The *graph* is exactly the same, but `HEAD` points to `temp` and `temp` points to commit `A`.  So now we might run:

```
git merge feature-branch
```

or:

```
git merge origin/feature-branch
```

This time Git will translate the string to the raw ID of commit `C`, and commit `C` is *not* an ancestor of `A`.  In fact, it's just the opposite, `A` is an ancestor of `C`, as we saw with the merge that did nothing.

Well, this time `git merge` does something, but it still does not have to make a merge *commit*.

Instead, it can simply "slide the branch name" (`temp`) "fast forward":

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch, HEAD->temp
```

Note that there is still no change in the graph.  All Git did was move `temp`, so that it now points to commit `C`.

#### Real merges and forced merges

Let's get yet another new branch:

```
git checkout -b t2 origin/v8.2
```

Draw the graph:

```
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2, HEAD->t2
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch, temp
```

Now make a new commit, let's call it `D`:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m dummy
```

Draw the graph again:

```
       D      <-- HEAD->t2
      /
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch, temp
```

(you can start to see why graph-drawing programs are either complicated, or produce poor graphs—I have to engineer this setup carefully to make the graph simple enough to draw!).  Now, while on `t2`, let's ask git to make a new merge with `temp` or `feature-branch` or `origin/feature/branch`.  It does not really matter which one we pick: the act of merging requires the same work, because they all end up pointing to commit `C`.

Now, since we're on branch `t2` which points to commit `D`, and we're merging commit `C`, `git merge` has to do some real work this time.  The reason is that `C` is not an ancestor of `D`, and `D` is not an ancestor of `C`.  They do, however, both have a *common* ancestor, namely commit `A`.

What `git merge` does now is compare commit `A` vs commit `D`, to see what we changed on our branch `t2`, and also compare commit `A` vs commit `C`, to see what they—whoever "they" may be—changed on the their other side of all this branching.

It then attempts to combine these changes, using a simple text-comparison algorithm that knows nothing about code.  If it believes it successfully combined the changes, it makes a new commit, a *merge* commit, with two parents, `D`—the commit we were on when we started—and `C`, the commit we named.

The *log message* for the new commit depends on which human-readable name we used, but the graph and the merge result do not: they depend only on commit `A`, the merge base, and commits `D` and `C`, the local and other commits.  So we get this:

```
       D------M    <-- HEAD->t2
      /      /
...--A        <-- origin/v8.2
      \    /
       B--C   <-- feature-branch, origin/feature-branch, temp
```

#### Using `--no-ff`

What if we don't have commit `D`, but we want to *force* a merge commit?

This is where `git merge --no-ff` comes in.  Using the `--no-ff` directive tells git that it should figure out what to merge.  If there is nothing to merge, stop as usual.  If there is something to merge, and it requires a regular merge, do a regular merge as usual.  But—here's the special case—if it *could* do a fast-forward, as happened with our branch `temp`, it *should not*.  It should instead make a real merge commit, with two parents.

This may be what you want.  Or, you might be happier with a fast-forward merge.  And, *all of this depends on the commit graph*.  I have been drawing this graph based on a bunch of assumptions I made.  Are they correct?  I don't know; only you (the OP) can tell.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, it has a huge array of options, but translating names to IDs is at least its original and still most-central function.

<sup>2</sup>For various reasons, Git has a special case for this: you are not on a *named* branch, but you are on the special anonymous (un-named) branch, which you can refer to by the name `HEAD`.  In other words, `HEAD` is always your current branch, even if you do not have a current branch.  The problem with the anonymous branch is that it goes away automatically when you `git checkout` a normal branch to get back on a branch.  This "problem" is also a very important *feature*: Git uses the anonymous branch to implement interactive rebase, for instance.  But mostly you don't need to know this.